# В phpstorm не видит :pattern

Tags: php, phpstorm, шаблоны

Случайным образом отключила какую-то функцию в phpstorm и после этого у меня во всем коде пропали шаблоны pattern:, path:, charlist: и т.д.
И раньше он их полсвечивал, а теперь подчеркивает красным двоеточие и считает ошибкой.